# Create a 3D video/animation for a presentation

Tags: c#, animation, 3d, blender

I need to create a 3D video/animation for a presentation. I'm currently designing models with Blender and seems pretty easy to use.

Anyway I'd like to let the argue following the animation just like a powerpoint presentation (I click a key -> the animation unrolls a little, I click the back/leftarrow key -> the animation rewinds rapidly, I press space -> the animation stops while some elements still hang around)

I already did this with blender animations and C# to control videos, but I'd like to know whether there are other (potentially better) options to achieve this (like: exporting from blender to XAML and then using WPF.. really heavy though). Otherwise I'll stick with what I've already done

Comment: hmmm, I just googled for "Blender XAML" and there are [exporters](http://xamlexporter.codeplex.com/) out there. Haven't tried any, but hopefully, there's something that supports the features you need.

Comment: Yes I used it once, but XAML is really really heavy on importing into the IDE.. for complex models it isn't the right choice

Comment: Sorry, but C# is not my strong point. I imagine a library that loads binary formats (e.g. .3ds, .md2) might be handy in this case. Even .obj should be less verbose than the xml format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My temporary solution is: using blender for both animation and modeling. There are great tutorials out there